# Which test do I need for testing differences in two populations?

Tags: statistical-significance, group-differences, differences, mortality

I would like to compare the different variables in a life table of two populations and check if the differences are significant. However, I am totally unsure which test is appropriate.
For example, I wanted to test if life expectancy is different in population A (50 individuals) and B (70 individuals).
Life expectancy was calculated in 5-year-intervals (i.e., 0-4 years, 5-9 years, 10-15 years, etc.) resulting in a decreasing value with increasing age:
[image]

I already visually checked life expectancy and population A has a lower life expectancy than population B. Now I would like to test if this difference is significant, but which test is the right one? Is it a simple t-test? Or rather Mann–Whitney-U/Wilcoxon’s tests? Or another?
I am having a really hard time with statistics and therefore would appreciate some explanations which test, why, and how?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by a “population”?

Comment: Are these populations of people?  If so, which people? The numbers seem very strange.  There is no country on Earth with a life expectancy at birth that is even close to this low. And, even if these are not people but some shorter-lived creature, the numbers seem odd. If the LE is 21 at birth, then ... how does anyone make it to 60?

Comment: @PeterFlom I do not understand that last comment. Human life expectancy is about 80, yet people make it to 90 and 100.

Comment: @Dave So? That sort of makes my point. Human LE is about 80 and the very oldest person is about 110.  Not LE of about 20 and still a long life expectancy at age 60.

Comment: How does a life expectancy of 20 preclude survival past 60?

Comment: Values in published life tables are smoothed. I don't think you can treat the values as independent (nor as homoskedastic)

Comment: First of all, thanks for all the comments!
Sorry for being unclear, I am studying skeletal remains from archaeological context. Thus, a population referts to all individuals from a cemetery. Therefore, LE at birth of about 20 years is not unusual, while still having some "old aged" individuals. I hope it is more clear now and contributes to my question, which test is appropriate?
@Glen_b sorry, but I can't follow you. What do you mean?

Comment: 1. How were the life expectancy values in your table obtained? It would seem odd to estimate life expectancies without smoothing mortality but perhaps that didn't happen. 2.  even if some form of model fit/smoothing wasn't done, presumably the expectancies themselves rely on some common data (since all the average complete lifetimes from some age include old-age mortality). 3. Either way, the expectancy figures are not independent.  4. Similarly, any way of calculating a sample-based life expectancy that I can think of will have different standard errors at each age. (heteroskedasticity)

Comment: I calculated an abridged (since exact age estimations are not possible in skeletal material) life table containing Dx, dx, lx, qx, Lx, Tx, ex, for each of the two populations/cemeteries. The two clumns life_exp_A and life_exp_B are in fact just extracted from the two life tables representing ex of the populations. I calculated ex by dividing Tx (person-years lived above age x) through lx (number of people left alive at age x). No smoothing has been done.